# Customizing how Solr searches a specific field

Tags: solr

I am trying to see if its possible to customize solr to change the way it searches for a specific field.

To better understand the context and the question, here is what i want to do -  i have 5 fields and all of them will be text fields [dont read too much into the syntax .. ]

```
<field>a</field> ==> will contain normal text [lazy fox jumps over ..]
<field>b</field> ==> will contain normal text [lazy fox jumps over ..]
<field>c</field> ==> will contain numbers separated by a delimiter [1, 2, 4, 6]
<field>d</field> ==> will contain numbers separated by a delimiter [1, 2, 4, 6]
<field>e</field> ==> will contain numbers separated by a delimiter [1, 2, 4, 6]
```

my query will search against all these 5 fields and the values for the fields c, d & e will also contain numerical values separated by commas.

while searching i would like to perform an intersection between the value in the query & the value within the field in the index. How can i do that?

=> the other way to look at the problem is that if one of the values in the query field is present in the field within the index, then i should match this document to be returned back. This looks like a simple "OR" search but the values within each field could be in the order of 100's .. so constructing an OR query for that many possible input values wont be pretty i guess. If that scales well, then that could be a possible solution, but was not sure if it will scale well.

How can I implement such a customization? - search/query performance is a key factor that will be considered.

Answer (score 0):

for fields c d and e you should split the values by  the delimiter , and store as multivalued field, which will allow you to match against each single value.

so your query becomes

```
q=a:(query) b:(query) c:(query) d:(query) e:(query)
```

assuming that the default query operator is OR.

Comment: The default query operator is applicable only between the fields correct? ie., between a, b, c, d and e.

Can you specify a default query operator for across the different fields and within each field? - the other way is to set the default o be OR and specify AND explicitly in the query.

Comment: no, default operator will work across any terms separated by space unless we make them phrase by enclosing in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

for fields c d and e you should split the values (by the delimiter) into another multivalued field. As @Umar suggests.  You will then have a single field for searching the numbers with (let this field by called "numbers").

so your query becomes

q=a:(query) b:(query) numbers:(query)

assuming that the default query operator is OR.

the field "numbers" should be string if you just want simple equality searching.  It should be int if you want to allow range searching on these numbers.

If you're concerned that the numbers will not always be in a predictable format (ie comes from user input), you may elect to copy the contents of fields c thru e into a single text field.  This will give you a much looser matching capability but you won't be able to do range searches and the like.  IIRC, SOLR's copy field will allow you to specify many source fields to one target field without complaining but when you load documents the target field will get the contents of the last copyField that was executed.  So that won't work here and you will need to concatenate the contents to a single field in your code.

Comment: The issue is that i cannot merge all these values into one field. They are like access control and each field has a significance and even if one of the fields doesnt match then i should not match the document. It is an AND across these different fields.

Comment: then just use text fields for all and use AND inside the parens and OR's between fields.  easy.  Group any field queries with parens.  eg. (a:(query) AND b:(query)) OR (c:(query) OR d:(q1 AND q2)) or whatever logical expression you imagine.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, will try that out. any clues on how the performance will be when we have thousands of items within each field?

is there a way to write a custom search component that can do this in an efficient way within Solr. By the above approach we are increasing the query terms by a huge number and this will be applicable for each and every search on the system, so i was a little worried on how this design will perform.

Answer (score -1):

You may use copyField option. Create some field with some name for example 'composite'.

```
<field name="composite" type="sometype" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true">
```

*set stored option false to avoid excessive memory usage.*

The same type as c d & e. Copy a c d & e fields to `'composite'`.

```
<copyField source="c" dest="composite">

<copyField source="d" dest="composite">

<copyField source="e" dest="composite">
```

Then your query will looks like as below:

```
q=a:(query) AND composite:(query)
```

Comment: you can only use copyField one source to one target.  Not many to one as you propose.

Comment: the use of copyField above is right, solr allows to copy as many as desired fields into a single destination field. If you even check the example you can see the use of text as copy field in the default schema file. Although one thing needs to be taken care that the destination field is defined as a multivalued field.